# Lookup without looping

Tags: r

I have two tables, and I'm trying to look up values from one to add to values in the other. Currently I am using two for loops but they run slowly. I am new to R and know I should avoid looping to speed things up but I can't figure out how.

Table1 (several thousand rows, 37 columns):

```
type cat1 cat2 cat3 ... cat36
   1    2    3    2         7
   3    6    2    1         9
   2    4    6    7         4
   3    5    7    8         2
   5    2    2    9         1
   4    3    1    2         3
   1    8    1    4         4
...
```

Table2 (36 rows, 5 columns):

```
      type1 type2 type3 type4 type5
cat1      2     3     4     3     8
cat2      8     5     5     2     6
cat3      7     5     1     3     5
...
cat36     4     7     2     8     9
```

I want to modify each value in Table1 by adding the appropriate value (matching among the 5 types and 36 categories) from Table2. Here are the desired results:

```
type cat1 cat2 cat3 ... cat36
   1    4   11    9        11
   3   10    7    2        11
   2    7   11   12        11
   3    9   12    9         4
   5   10    8   14        10
   4    6    3    5        11
   1   10    9   11         8
...
```

Here is my current (slow) code:

```
for (i in 1:36) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(Table1)) {
        Table1[j,i+1] = Table1[j,i+1] + Table2[i,Table1[j,1]]
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I used two loops for clarity, I will note that I could have just had one loop through the rows of Table1, adding the appropriate column from Table2 to each Table1 row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type column in Table1 indicates which *column* in Table2 to add to the *rows* in Table1. So use the "type" column as an index to the Table2 rows, and then transpose the resulting matrix so you can add rows to rows:

```
Table3 <- cbind(Table1[ , "type"], 
                t(Table2[ , Table1[ , "type"] ]) + Table1[ , -1])
```

(I'm assuming that Table1 and Table2 are matrices. If they are data frames you can use `Table1$type` instead of `Table1[,"type"]`).

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work after correcting one typo. Instead of `Table2[Table1[ , "type"] , ]` it should be `Table2[ , Table1[ , "type"]]`

Comment: Oops, you're right. I got mixed up transposing between rows and columns!

Answer (score 1):

I would transform both tables to be "long" instead of two differing "wide" formats. After making both tables long you could perform a merge (R data.frame analog to an SQL join) on the two tables and then trivially sum the values.

Here's a similar example:

```
## creating some synthetic data
df1 <- data.frame(type=sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE), cat1=sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE), cat2=sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE),cat3=sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE),cat4=sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE) )
df2 <- data.frame(cat=1:4, type1=sample(1:4,4), type2=sample(1:4,4), type3=sample(1:4,4), type4=sample(1:4,4) )

require(reshape)

## rearrange df1
m1 <- melt(df1, id.vars="type")
m1$cat <- substr(m1$variable, 4,4)
m1$variable <- NULL

## rearrange df2
m2 <- melt(df2, id.vars="cat")
m2$type <- substr(m2$variable, 5, 5)
m2$value2 <- m2$value
m2$variable <- NULL
m2$value <- NULL

## now that they are laid out the same, they can be merged
df3 <- merge(m1, m2)
df3$newSum <- df3$value + df3$value2
```