# Assign values based on "insufficient" look-up table

Tags: r, merge, lookup

I have to look up some scores and assign percentile value based on a fixed look-up table.

I've tried to solve this problem for some time now, and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037786/lookup-without-looping) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057113/lookup-values-in-a-vectorized-way) SO thread, but without solving my problem. My problem is that the raw score can be bigger then the values in the look-up table, in such cases the biggest percentile value is prescribed.

I have a look-up table like this,

```
lookup <- structure(list(Percentile = c(99, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 1), ACB = c(24, 19, 18, 17, 16, NA, 15, NA, 14, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, 11, 10, 9, 7), DFG = c(49, 39, 36, 33, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, NA, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 17, 14, 12), EIH = c(35, 30, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, NA, 14, NA, 13, 12, NA), GKJ = c(49, 39, 36, 33, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, NA, 24, 23, 22, 21, 19, 18, 17, 15, 14), Total = c(112, 99, 91, 86, 82, 79, 76, 75, 73, 71, 69, 67, 66, 65, 63, 61, 59, 55, 51, 46, 39)), .Names = c("Percentile", "ACB", "DFG", "EIH", "GKJ", "Total"), row.names = c("99+", "95", "90", "85", "80", "75", "70", "65", "60", "55", "50", "45", "40", "35", "30", "25", "20", "15", "10", "5", "1"), class = "data.frame")
lookup
    Percentile ACB DFG EIH GKJ Total
99+         99  24  49  35  49   112
95          95  19  39  30  39    99
90          90  18  36  27  36    91
85          85  17  33  26  33    86
80          80  16  31  25  31    82
75          75  NA  30  24  30    79
70          70  15  29  23  29    76
65          65  NA  28  22  28    75
60          60  14  27  21  27    73
55          55  NA  26  20  26    71
50          50  NA  25  19  25    69
45          45  13  NA  18  NA    67
40          40  NA  24  17  24    66
35          35  NA  23  16  23    65
30          30  NA  22  15  22    63
25          25  12  21  NA  21    61
20          20  NA  20  14  19    59
15          15  11  19  NA  18    55
10          10  10  17  13  17    51
5            5   9  14  12  15    46
1            1   7  12  NA  14    39
```

and, som raw data that looks like this,

```
rawS_1 <- structure(list(ACB = 28, DFG = 39, EIH = 31, GKJ = NA_real_, Total = NA_real_), .Names = c("ACB", "DFG", "EIH", "GKJ", "Total"), row.names = "RawScore for ID 1", class = "data.frame")
rawS_1
                  ACB DFG EIH GKJ Total
RawScore for ID 1  28  39  31  NA    NA

rawS_2 <- structure(list(ACB = 29, DFG = 51, EIH = 56, GKJ = 60, Total = 169), .Names = c("ACB", "DFG", "EIH", "GKJ", "Total"), row.names = "RawScore for ID 2", class = "data.frame")
rawS_2
                  ACB DFG EIH GKJ Total
RawScore for ID 2  29  51  56  60   169
```

and, this is what I would like to do,

```
                  ACB DFG EIH GKJ Total
RawScore for ID 1  12  39  19  NA    NA
Percentile, ID 1   25  95  50  NA    NA
                  ACB DFG EIH GKJ Total
RawScore for ID 2  29  51  56  60   169
Percentile, ID 2   99  99  99  99    99
```

I've tried to `merge()` with `all.x = TRUE` and `suffixes = c(".x",".y"))`, but I keep getting *what I don't want* and help would be appreciated.

Comment: example of the merge code you've tried?

Comment: I'd use something like lapply(raws.list, function(x) ifelse(x > max.raw.score, x[,"percentile"] = 99, merge(x, lookup))) or some variant based on what you need.. I'm guessing because you didn't provide enough info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than thinking of this as merging, I think you're better off thinking it as a problem of creating a function: you want a function that when given the raw value of (e.g.) ACB returns the percentile.  Luckily R has a function designed to make a function from a table of numbers: `approxfun`.

The following code uses `lapply` to create a function for each column, and then shows how to call the the new functions:

```
vars <- names(lookup)[-1]
lookup_funs <- lapply(vars, function(var) {
  df <- data.frame(x = lookup[[var]], y = lookup$Percentile)
  df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
  approxfun(df$x, df$y, "constant", rule = 2)
})
names(lookup_funs) <- vars

lookup_funs$ACB(c(12, 29))
lookup_funs$Total(169)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic strategy is to use `!is.na(vec)` to index both the value and the percetile vectors. Here's a look at a single case. Which one would you prefer for input of 11 for ACB?

```
> rev(lookup$Percentile)[!is.na(lookup$ACB)][
                findInterval( 11, c(-Inf,rev(lookup$ACB[!is.na(lookup$ACB)]), Inf))]
[1] 20
> rev(lookup$Percentile)[!is.na(lookup$ACB)][
                findInterval( 11, c(-Inf,rev(lookup$ACB[!is.na(lookup$ACB)]), Inf))-1]
[1] 15
```

This gets you most of the way there for one row of data:

```
> for(i in names(rawS_1) ) {print(rawS_1[i]); print(rev(lookup$Percentile)[ !is.na(lookup[[i]]) ][ findInterval( rawS_1[i], c( rev( lookup[[i]][ !is.na(lookup[[i]] )]) ) )] )}
                  ACB
RawScore for ID 1  28
[1] 99
                  DFG
RawScore for ID 1  39
[1] 95
                  EIH
RawScore for ID 1  31
[1] 90
                  GKJ
RawScore for ID 1  NA
[1] NA
                  Total
RawScore for ID 1    NA
[1] NA
```

You do get into indexing overruns with the subtraction of 1 from indices at the high end of the scale, so you probably ought to add an extra element on the lookup vector after you decide what result you want to see.

```
for(i in names(rawS_2) ) {print(rawS_2[i]); print(rev(lookup$Percentile)[ !is.na(lookup[[i]]) ][ findInterval( rawS_2[i], c( rev( lookup[[i]][ !is.na(lookup[[i]] )]) ) )] )}
                  ACB
RawScore for ID 2  29
[1] 99
                  DFG
RawScore for ID 2  51
[1] 99
                  EIH
RawScore for ID 2  56
[1] 95
                  GKJ
RawScore for ID 2  60
[1] 99
                  Total
RawScore for ID 2   169
[1] 99
```